# Adding Winsock2 to my MinGW-w64 C/C++ causes: undefined reference to `InitializeConditionVariable'

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, winsock, mingw-w64

When I add winsock2 to my MinGW-w64 C/C++ project, it then gets make error:
undefined reference to `InitializeConditionVariable'.

NOTE: InitializeConditionVariable built and ran ok prior to adding Winsock.

main.c ...

```
    #undef UNICODE
    
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    
    
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    
    #include "infrastructure.h"
    #include "common.h"
    #include "bg.h"
    #include "aox.h"
    
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    
    #include <synchapi.h>

. . . 

static void mutexInit()
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
  // Initialize critical sections and condition variables
  InitializeCriticalSection(&iqSamplesCriticalSection);
  InitializeCriticalSection(&bgBufferCriticalSection);
  InitializeConditionVariable(&newSamplesAvailable);   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR: undefined reference
#else
  // Initialize mutexes
  pthread_mutex_init(&iqSamplesCriticalSection, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_init(&bgBufferCriticalSection, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&newSamplesAvailable,NULL);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `std` mutexes and condition variables? Also, I think some versions of MinGW (the MSYS2 one at least) include a Windows port of pthreads.

Comment: HBC: ...because I "inherited" the code.  yes, one solution is to replace mutexes with std.

Comment: "*NOTE: InitializeConditionVariable built and ran ok prior to adding Winsock*" - I find that highly unlikely. There is nothing the WinSock API does that could affect how the compiler+linker process `InitializeConditionVariable()`. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

[`InitializeConditionVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializeconditionvariable) has nothing to do with WinSock.  This is strictly an issue with your own code.

`InitializeConditionVariable()` was introduced in Windows Vista.  You are likely just linking to an out-dated `kernel32.lib` that doesn't expose newer Vista+ APIs. So, you can either:

- update the Windows SDK for your compiler.
- load the various [ConditionVariable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/condition-variables) dynamically at runtime using [`GetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress).

Comment: MSYS2 GCC compiles `InitializeConditionVariable` out of the box, without any extra flags. Not sure how to update Windows SDK on MinGW, so it might be easier to just switch to MSYS2.

Comment: Compiling and linking are two different steps. You are getting a linker error, not a compiler error. Your MinGW's copy of `kernel32.lib` likely does not have an entry to import `InitializeConditionVariable()` from `kernel32.dll`, like it does for `InitializeCriticalSection()` (which is a much older API). You could check if MinGW has any tool for regenerating its `kernel32.lib` from `kernel32.dll` itself.

Comment: Used the wrong word, I'm sorry. Should've said "builds out of the box". It compiles, links and runs without any errors.

Comment: Note: InitializeConditionVariable built and ran ok prior to adding Winsock.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. See my other comment.

Comment: Thank you, Remy.  ...will try those tips.

Comment: Remy:  Nevertheless, that's what happens:  Before I paste in the Winsock includes, it links and runs and uses the mutex based on InitializeConditionVariable. I add the Winsock includes and InitializeConditionVariable undefined.

Comment: @DougNull Can you make a [mcve] perhaps? Two short snippets that differ only in includes, and only one of them works.